# The method setText(String) is undefined for the type JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel

```
private JPanel textField = new JPanel();

public class Moves extends JFrame implements Observer {
     public Moves(final CLASS1 class1){
        textField.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textField, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    textField.add(new JTextField("Moved: " + hm.getMoveCount()));
     }
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg){ 
        textField.setText("Update: " + hm.updateMoves());

    }
}
```

below the update method, .setText(String) is undefined for the type JPanel. How would I fix this?

My bad. I was wrong. I wish I can delete this. I put JPanel instead of JTextField.

Thank you.

Solution for the people:
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField();

```
public class Moves extends JFrame implements Observer {
     public Moves(final CLASS1 class1){
        textField.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textField, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        textField.add(new JTextField("Moved: " + hm.getMoveCount()));
     }
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg){ 
        textField.setText("Update: " + hm.updateMoves());

    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPanel doesn't have a method `setText(String)`.

You might be looking for `setTitle(String)` in JFrame.

Comment: My bad. I was wrong. I wish I can delete this. I put JPanel instead of JTextField.

Comment: @user3557085 Don't delete this, that doesn't help anyone (except you which ruins the point of SO and is just selfish in itself). Just leave it be. Glad I could help though :)

Comment: This type of question considered as off topic on SO because it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or its a simple typographical error

Comment: @ImmerAllein Then it should be flagged and closed, not taken down.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I **do** voted to close, and I **didn't** downvote